# PHP To Check If Variable Is Set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I am wanting to use one page that is linked to from two different pages.  Below are my scenarios:

> 1) The user clicks a hyperlink to be directed to the page with a salesID in the URL
>   2) The user navigates directly to the page and no salesID is passed in the URL

Now to account for each situation above ->

> 1) If salesID IS NULL then get parameters from the page
>   
> 2) If salesID IS NOT NULL then onload() display all relevant data for the salesID passed

I know how to write the query to load the page by default with a parameter, and I know how to load the page with parameters captured on the page from a button press event.  What I do not know how to do is to combine the two and check multiple criteria.  What I want to do is on pageload() evaluate criteria 1 - if a salesID is passed to the page, then go ahead and populate the page with all data for that salesID.  If criteria 2 is true, then do not populate the page, wait for user input to select from select boxes and push the button.

This is basics of how I have the syntax for the page:

```
<?php
    //Capture variable from URL
    $salesID = urldecode($_GET['salesID']);

    //Check if variable is set
    if (isset($_GET['salesID'])) {
        //A salesID was passed to the page so load that data by default
        //ignoring any variables set on the page
    }
    else {
        if (isset($_POST['btnpressevent'])) {
            //button has been pressed capture variables from page and run query
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why don't you just populate the form with PHP then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:-

```
    // if salesId is not set or is null then show form with select and button

 if (!isset($_GET['salesId']) || is_null($_GET['salesId'])) {
      $html = "<form action='samepage.php'><select><option>Select one</option><option>Item 1</option></select><button name='btnpressevent'>Press button</button></form>";
      echo $html;
      return; // or die();
    }

    // do stuff with salesId
    echo "${$_GET['salesId']} helllo w";
```

Comment: Please read about what `isset()` checks for.  Your condition is too verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$salesID = urldecode($_GET['salesID']);` to `$salesID = to_utf8($_GET['salesID']);`

and then simply `if(isset($salesID) {}`

GET is already decoded and you've already declared it as a variable.

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking beyond it generally not working, but those two changes should help it work as intended.